# how to hide a datagrid detail row

Tags: silverlight, mvvm-light

I have a datagrid with the `RowDetialsVisibilityMode` set to `VisibleWhenSelected`, and the RowDetailsTemplate set accordingly.  When the user selects a row, the detail shows, which is exactly as described. However after reviewing the details, the user would like to hide the row detail again without showing the details of another row. How is this best accomplished.

**Update:** As mentioned in the comments, the likely the best option would be a button in the details row to hide the row, but then I wonder what would the binding look like?

Comment: Do you want a button in the row details that collapses the row details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this functionality is presentation-based,  I'd create a behavior for the button that would collapse the row

```
public class CollapseRowAction : TriggerAction<ButtonBase>
{
    public CollapseRowAction() {}
    protected override void Invoke(object o)
    {
        var dg = FindVisualParent<DataGrid>(this.AssociatedObject);
        if (dg != null)
            dg.SelectedIndex = -1;

    }

    private static T FindVisualParent<T>(DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
    {      

        DependencyObject parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);   
        if (parentObject == null) return null; 

        T parent = parentObject as T;
        if (parent != null) 
        { 
            return parent; 
        }
        else
        {
            return FindVisualParent<T>(parentObject);
        }
    }
}
```

And in XAML:

```
<sdk:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <!--... However row details are presented ...-->
        <Button Margin="10" Content="Collapse">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <myTriggers:CollapseRowAction/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
</sdk:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

Comment: Actually that didn't quite work as expected.  Once we set the DetailsVisibility property explicitly the row no longer behaves according to the DataGrid.RowDetailsVisibilityMode setting which is set to VisibleWhenSelected.  Suggestions?

Comment: I've done this in real life when creating a column with a +/- toggle button to toggle the row details.  I set the RowDetialsVisibilityMode to Collapsed,  then I've either set a behavior to the button to toggle back and forth from Collapsed to Visible, or in code-behind created a binding between the button IsPressed and the Row's DetailsVisibility (using a ValueConverter)  (must be in code and not XAML until SL5 comes out with a stronger RelativeSource binding).  Been meaning to blog about it...

Comment: I've edited the answer to unselect the row, thereby hiding the row details instead of changing the DetailsVisibility, which as you said, doesn't work.